# Test for monotonicity between consecutive zero first derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function that is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $x_1 < x_2$ are two consecutive roots of $f'$, and we also know that $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

Is it true that $f$ is strictly monoconically decreasing on $[x_1,x_2]$?

I also ask for a justification.

Comment: The conclusion follows from Rolle's theorem.

Comment: $f'$ keeps the same sign on $(x_1,x_2)$ since the roots are consecutive, and that sign must be negative since $f(x_1) \gt f(x_2)$.

Comment: @dxiv This is all we know. We do not know the sign of the derivative at any point in between.

Comment: The derivative satisfies the Darboux property, therefore  its sign must be constant on $(x_1,x_2).$

Comment: You know by MVT that there is a point $c \in (x_1,x_2)$ where $f'(c) \lt 0$. You also know that $f'$ can't change sign inside $(x_1,x_2)$ because that would imply another root in the interval (since derivatives have the Darboux property). Therefore $f' \lt 0$ on the whole interval, which is sufficient for $f$ to be strictly decreasing on said interval.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Thank you for your comments. The sign must be constant on $(x_1, x_2)$, this is clear.

Comment: Think at how it could *not* be strictly decreasing on the closed interval. It would require the value at one of the endpoints to equal the value at another point, which would necessarily be inside the open interval. By monotonicity, the function would have to be flat between those two points, which contradicts the derivative being negative on the open interval.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction there are two points $x_1\le x_3<x_4\le x_2$ such that $f(x_3)\le f(x_4).$

1. $f(x_3)=f(x_4)$

By the Rolle theorem the derivative vanishes at some point $t,$ $x_3<t<x_4.$

2. $f(x_3)<f(x_4)$

Since $f(x_1)>f(x_2),$ then either  $f(x_1)>f(x_3)$ or
$f(x_4)>f(x_2).$ In the first case $f(x_1)>f(x_3)<f(x_4),$ hence $f$ attains a local minimum in $(x_1,x_4).$ Similarly if $f(x_3)<f(x_4)>f(x_2)$ the function $f$ attains a local maximum in $(x_3,x_2).$ In either case the derivative vanishes somewhere in $(x_1,x_2).$

Comment: But Rolle's theorem uses the derivative of a function.

Comment: I meant that I didn't use the Darboux property of the derivative.